# Refresh data in dataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, datagridview

Not sure what I am doing wrong here.  I have a SQL server side VIEW which I am displaying in a DataGridView.  I am displaying everything fine, then I am updating the records fine, but when I try to refresh the data nothing happens.

```
    viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
    dgArchiveDups.Sort(batchNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
    dgArchiveDups.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh the data source on your grid.

Comment: How?  I have also tried:

viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheBindingSource.ResetBindings(false);
            
            dgArchiveDups.DataSource = null;
            dgArchiveDups.DataSource = viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheBindingSource;
            dgArchiveDups.Sort(batchNumberDataGridViewTextBoxColumn, ListSortDirection.Ascending);
            
            dgArchiveDups.Refresh();

Comment: Fetch the data again and then call ResetBindings(false)

Comment: I am using the Form based objects (viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheBindingSource, TestDataSet and viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheTableAdapter) that were created automatically when I added the DataGridView to my form if that makes any difference.

Comment: How do I fetch the data again?

Comment: Like how you did it the first time.

Comment: I'm using the form based controls.  I have no code where I am telling it to load the data

Comment: Should just be able to set the datasource to null then recall your code that you says works to display it.

Comment: Post the whole source

Comment: Figured it out.  I am fairly new to C# (not programming in general) but when I added the control it added this line to the form_load event:

            this.viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheTableAdapter.Fill(this.ediTestDataSet.ViewDuplicateBatchesInCache);


So I just copied that to the end of my code and I am good now.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I am fairly new to C# (not programming in general) but when I added the control it added this line to the form_load event:

this.viewDuplicateBatchesInCacheTableAdapter.Fill(this.TestDataSet.ViewDuplic‌​ateBatchesInCache);

So I just copied that to the end of my code and I am good now. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can accept my answer, since that was your problem